# Passing a large file stream to MultipartFormDataContent with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm experiencing a problem when trying to use `MultipartFormDataContent` with `HttpClient` with a stream of data.

## Context

I'm trying to upload a large file to ASP.NET Core Web API. A client should send the file via POST request form-data to a front-end API, which in turn should forward the file to a back-end API.

Because the file can be large, I followed [the Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming), i.e. **I don't want to use `IFormFile` type but instead read the `Request.Body` using `MultipartReader`**. This is to avoid loading the entire file into memory on the server, or saving it in a temporary file on server's hard drive.

## Problem

The back-end API controller action looks as follows (this is almost directly copied from the ASP.NET Core 5.0 [sample app](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/) with just minor simplifications):

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveLargeFile()
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Request;

            if (!request.HasFormContentType
                || !MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out var mediaTypeHeader)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value))
            {
                return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
            }

            var reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body);
            /* This throws an IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.  */
            var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
            
            while (section != null)
            {
                var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition,
                    out var contentDisposition);

                if (hasContentDispositionHeader
                    && contentDisposition!.DispositionType.Equals("form-data")
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
                {
                    /* Fake copy to nothing since it doesn't even get here */
                    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(Stream.Null);
                    return Ok();
                }

                section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
            }

            return BadRequest("No files data in the request.");
        }
```

I managed to reduce the problem slightly by making an integration test using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` NuGet package. The following test replaces the front-end API, so instead of reading `Request.Body` stream in a Web API, the test just tries to add `StreamContent` to `MultipartFormDataContent` and post it via `HttpClient` to the back-end API:

```cs
        [Fact]
        public async Task Client_posting_to_Api_returns_Ok()
        {
            /* Arrange */
            await using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            await using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("FILE CONTENTS");
            await writer.FlushAsync();
            stream.Position = 0;

            using var client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient();

            /* Act */
            using var response =
                await client.PostAsync(
                    "Receive",
                    new MultipartFormDataContent
                    {
                        {
                            new StreamContent(stream),
                            "file",
                            "fileName"
                        }
                    });
            
            /* Assert */
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

The back-end API controller then throws an `IOException` at `await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()`, saying "Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component".

## GitHub Repository (Complete Example)

I uploaded a complete example of the problem (including back-end API and the test) a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/piotr-consensus/StreamingMultipartFormData).

## Question

I must be doing something wrong. How can I forward a file received in a request with form-data content type in one service (front-end API) to another service (back-end API) without loading the entire file into memory or hard-drive in the front-end API, i.e. to just forward the stream of data to the back-end API?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to apply Saga Pattern. Read the file in small parts and send them one by one (or in parallel) to the second service until the full file was read.

Comment: Thanks @DA, do you have some resources where I could read about it? I don't know the pattern and Googling around gives me plenty of cloud specific articles, or ones using MassTransit etc. which I don't think is what I need for this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429726/httpclient-and-pushstreamcontent) help?

Comment: @Eldar not really, that question is about ASP.NET Web API 2.0 framework, which is significantly different than the "new" ASP.NET Core :(

Comment: The part you should be looking at is not the Web API part but the `HttpClient` part. Especially `httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` part (which is the same as .net 5). This allows you to forward your request stream by copying it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to see if I can make that work somehow. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

I expected the same issue as you and it turned out that the MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse method parses the boundary value wrong as it wraps the string with '"' characters, because HttpClient sends the content type header like this:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary="blablabla"
```

So for me the solution was to add a Trim() method to boundary like this and pass that to the *MultipartReader*

```
var boundary = mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value.Trim('"');
var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while and tbh I just bit the bullet and used `IFormFile`. But I will give a try to your workaround when I have some time to look into it :)